# linux mint: waiting for network configuration

Tags: linux-mint, networkmanager

I went to another place and my network(either wired or wi-fi) starts not working... For now, I have a workaround solution that every time I logged in I have to run `sudo service network-manager start` which give me the following information:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
network-manager start/running, process 2410
```

Before I start network-manager, I ran `status network-manager` which give me this:

```
network-manager stop/waiting
```

Before I log in, I'm stuck here for around 1 and half minutes.. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I Googled and found a workaround solution to change `/etc/init/failsafe.conf`, but since I didn't touch it before and my wifi works... there must be something wrong somewhere else...

BTW, this is my content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 1):

the "auto eth0" line forces the boot up to wait for eth0 to become available. the "dhcp" means that it has to talk to a dhcp server first.

So if at this new location you either don't plug in the Ethernet cable or there is no dhcp server there (maybe they use static addresses) then this fails.

Change the "auto eth0" to "allow-hotplug eth0" this way the boot will not wait, but the interface will come up whenever it is ready.